# Android Bluetooth one scan after another

Tags: android, bluetooth, network-scan

I'm having some issues getting more than one scan to run consecutively. Here is how I handle the action:

```
if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
            Log.w("Bluetooth", "SCAN STOPPED EVENT");
            try{
                mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.w("Bluetooth", ""+ex);
            }
        }
```

I get the following log output after I have scanned. In this example the scan found 5 devices.

```
(main) [1,17346] SCAN STOPPED EVENT
(524): mDeviceProperties size is 5
(524): mCache size is 5
(524): trying to delete object
(524): trying to delete object
(524): trying to delete object
(524): trying to delete object
(524): trying to delete object
(524): Deleting object00:AA:DD:FF:AA:44
(524): Deleting object77:DD:22:66:99:44
(524): Deleting object00:00:88:99:22:77
(524): Deleting object77:CC:33:CC:33:FF
(524): Deleting object66:33:44:00:33:88
(524): mDeviceProperties size is 0
(524): mCache size is 0
```

It's obviously going through some sort of process where it deletes all of the cached devices but it never starts the scan again.. Anyone have any suggestions on this?

Comment: I have no idea why but if I run `mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();` three times before I try to scan again it works. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: And to actually stop scanning before the scan times out, I have to call `mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();` twice.